# How to handle different logic on the same branch

Tags: git

This seems like a easy one yet I'm struggling to find the correct way to do it, more cause I'm not git expert.

Say that I have 10 clients using my app. Each one of them have it's own business logic etc so the code isn't exactly the same for all of them but since there will be bugs to fix, once I fix it should be propagated to all its different branchs.

What is the git way to do that (if its even possible)?

Thanks!

Comment: The client-specific code should be isolated into modules, with the appropriate module deployed and imported for each client. This is independent of any branching model within Git, or even of the source control system you choose to use.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how the same fix could apply to all different systems?
I think the suggestion Rodrigo did, to split the differences into seperate modules, would be a good start.
After that, working with the git 'feature-branch-model' could make sense.
see https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow